# Drop Down List in ASP.Net, how to bind it to a property of a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have drop down list which need to take all the values from the property Items which are stored in `List< Person>`. My var model is accepting all the information from my `list`.

```
string text=File.ReadAllText(@"...");

List< Person > model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< List< Person>>(text)
```

my drop down list code:

```
< asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dpdTags"  >
```

So how I can bind the needed data to the drop down list?

Comment: dpdTags.Items.AddRange(model); or if that doesn't work, dpdTags.Items.AddRang(model.ToArray());

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger well if I add to dpsTags the variable model, won't it just accept all the values which are stored in the List? I just want to take the values which are stored in the tab Items of the List<Person>. I mean my list<Person> has 3 properties, name/address and the 3rd one is Items where are stored 7values

Comment: In that case, you can databind or use dpd.Items.AddRange(Person.Select(p=>p.{PropertyName}).ToArray()) where {PropertyName} = the property you want shown in the listview. This also give you the ablility to sort your list if you'd like: dpd.Items.AddRange(Person.Select(p=>p.{PropertyName}).OrderBy(p=p.{PropertyName}).ToArray())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dpdTags.DataSource = model;
dpdTags.DataTextField = "PersonText";
dpdTags.DataValueField = "PersonValue";
dpdTags.DataBind();
```

Try use this

Answer (score 0):

i think it is useful for you

```
List<Person> people = GetDataFromSomewhere();
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.DataTextField = "Name";
ddl.DataValueField = "Id";
ddl.DataSource = people;
ddl.DataBind();
ddl.SelectedValue = (from p in people
                     where p.Selected == true
                     select p.Id).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```